# Turtle not moving

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

This is a snakes and ladders script that uses tkinter and turtle.

**My Issue is that the counters(turtles) do no move past square 23 and I do not know why.**

The code is very long but I have added comments near the important area.
You can run it if you like to see what I mean

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
x = Tk()
totalp1 = 1
currentp1 = 0
totalp2 = 1
currentp2 = 0






import turtle
import time
a = 0
turtle.speed(0)
p1=turtle.Turtle()
p1.color("blue")
p2=turtle.Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-550,-350)
turtle.pendown()
p2.shape("circle")
turtle.pensize(2)
p1.shape("circle")
p1.resizemode("user")
p1.shapesize(1, 1, 1)
p1.penup()
p2.penup()
p1.hideturtle()
p2.hideturtle()

popo =0



def square():
    global popo
    popo += 1
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(75)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(75)
    turtle.write(str(popo), font=("Comic Sans MS", 10))
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(75)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(25)
    turtle.pendown()
def forwardrow():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(7):
        square()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(180)

def backrow():
    for i in range(7):
        square()
        turtle.forward(-200)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(-200)
    turtle.left(-90)
    turtle.forward(-100)
    turtle.left(-90)
    turtle.forward(-100)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.pendown()

def row():
    for i in range(7):
        square()


def grid():

        forwardrow()

        backrow()

        forwardrow()

        backrow()

        forwardrow()

        backrow()

        forwardrow()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-351, -250)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.pencolor("white")
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.forward(100)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-351, -50)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.pencolor("white")
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.forward(-100)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-351, 150)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.pencolor("white")
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.forward(100)
        p1.goto(-300, -275)
        p2.goto(-300, -325)
        turtle.pensize(8.76)
        turtle.color('green')
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(175,-25)
        turtle.write(str('ladder'))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(75,175)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(275,-225)
        turtle.write(str('ladder'))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(-125,-25)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-225,-325)
        turtle.write(str('ladder'))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(-125,75)
        turtle.color('red')
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(175,275)
        turtle.write(str('snake'))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(-225,-225)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-325,75)
        turtle.write(str('snake'))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(-225,-125)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-325,175)
        turtle.write(str('snake'))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(75,-25)
        turtle.penup()

        p1.showturtle()
        p2.showturtle()

#THIS IS FOR PLAYER ONE--------------------------------
def p1goto():
    global totalp1
    global currentp1
    while currentp1!=0:
        print (currentp1)
        currentp1-=1
        if (p1.xcor() == 200) and (p1.ycor() == 25):
            p1.forward(100)
        if (p1.xcor() == -300) and (p1.ycor() == -275):
            p1.setheading(0)
            p1.forward(100)
        elif (p1.xcor() == 300) and (p1.ycor() in [-275, -75, 125, 325]):
            p1.setheading(90)
            p1.forward(100)
        elif (p1.xcor() == -300) and (p1.ycor() in [-175, 25, 225]):
            p1.setheading(90)
            p1.forward(100)
        elif (p1.ycor() in [-275, -75, 125, 325]) and (p1.xcor() != 300):
            p1.setheading(0)
            p1.forward(100)
        elif (p1.ycor() in [-175, 25, 175, 225, 75]) and (p1.xcor() != -300):
            print("I Ran")
            p1.setheading(180)
            p1.forward(100)
    print (p1.pos())

def p1check():
    global totalp1
    if totalp1 == 2:
        totalp1 = 31

    elif totalp1 == 8:
        totalp1 = 26
        p1.goto()
    elif totalp1 == 23:
        totalp1 = 38
    elif totalp1 == 48:
        totalp1 = 13
    elif totalp1 == 42:
        totalp1 = 24
    elif totalp1 == 29:
        totalp1 = 16

#THIS IS FOR PLAYER TWO--------------------------------
def p2goto():
    global totalp2
    global currentp2
    while currentp2!=0:
        currentp2-=1
        if (p2.xcor() == -300) and (p2.ycor() == -275):
            p2.setheading(0)
            p2.forward(100)
            print("yep1")
        elif (p2.xcor() == 300) and (p2.ycor() in [-325, -125, 75, 275]):
            p2.setheading(90)
            p2.forward(100)
            print("yep2")
        elif (p2.xcor() == -300) and (p2.ycor() in [-225, -25, -175]):
            p2.setheading(90)
            p2.forward(100)
            print("yep3")
        elif (p2.ycor() in [-325, -125, 75, 275, 125]) and (p2.xcor() != 300):
            p2.setheading(0)
            p2.forward(100)
            print("yep4")
        elif (p2.ycor() in [-225, -25, 175]) and (p2.xcor() != -300):
            print("yep5")
            p2.setheading(180)
            p2.forward(100)
    print (p2.pos())





def clicked():
    nam1.pack_forget()
    name1.pack_forget()
    nam2.pack_forget()
    name2.pack_forget()
    btn.pack_forget()
    grid()
    rollingp1()

nam1 = Label(x, text = "       Player 1 Name       ", bg = "#6DE248")
name1 = Entry(x, bg = "#8486A4")
nam2 = Label(x, text = "       Player 2 Name       ", bg = "#487EE2")
name2 = Entry(x, bg = "#8486A4")
btn = Button(x, text = "-->", command=clicked, width= 10, height = 3, bg = "#E24C48")

nam1.pack()

name1.pack()

nam2.pack()

name2.pack()

btn.pack()

x.resizable(0,0)

def rollingp1():
    global totalp2
    global totalp1
    global currentp1
    a=random.randint(1,6)
    currentp1 = a
    totalp1 += currentp1

    def show():
        global totalp1
        global totalp2
        w = str(totalp1)
        print(name1.get() + " is on the " + w + "th square")
        p1goto()
        if (totalp2 < 49) and (totalp1 < 49):
            close()
            rollingp2()
        elif totalp1 >= 49:
            p1win()
        elif totalp2 >= 49:
            p2win()

    def close():
        playerroll.pack_forget()
        message.pack_forget()
        roll.pack_forget()


    playerroll = Label(x, text = name1.get() + " rolled : " + str(a))
    message = Label(x, text = name1.get() + "'s Turn", font =("Comic Sans MS", 17, "bold"))
    message.pack()
    roll = Button(x, text="""Click
    To
    Roll...""", width = 10, height = 3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 22, "bold"), bg="#E24C48", command=show)
    roll.pack()
    x.resizable(0,0)
    x.title("Dice")
    def p1win():
        playerroll.pack_forget()
        message.pack_forget()
        roll.pack_forget()
        webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M&feature=youtu.be&t=42")

    def p2win():
        playerroll2.pack_forget()
        message2.pack_forget()
        roll2.pack_forget()
        webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M&feature=youtu.be&t=42")




def rollingp2():
    global totalp1
    global totalp2
    global currentp2
    a2=random.randint(1,6)
    currentp2 = a2
    totalp2 += currentp2

    def show2():
        global totalp1
        global totalp2
        print(name2.get() +" is on the " + str(totalp2) +"th square")
        p2goto()
        if (totalp2 < 49) and (totalp1 < 49):
            print("it ran")
            close2()
            rollingp1()
        elif totalp1 >= 49:
            p1win()
        elif totalp2 >= 49:
            p2win()
    def close2():
        playerroll2.pack_forget()
        message2.pack_forget()
        roll2.pack_forget()

    playerroll2 = Label(x, text = name2.get() + " rolled : " + str(a2) + """
    They are on the """ + str(totalp2))
    message2 = Label(x, text =name2.get() + "'s Turn", font =("Comic Sans MS", 17, "bold"))

    message2.pack()
    roll2 = Button(x, text="""Click
    To
    Roll...""", width = 10, height = 3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 22, "bold"), bg="#E24C48", command=show2)
    roll2.pack()
    x.resizable(0,0)
    def p1win():
        playerroll.pack_forget()
        message.pack_forget()
        roll.pack_forget()

        webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M&feature=youtu.be&t=42")


    def p2win():
        playerroll2.pack_forget()
        message2.pack_forget()
        roll2.pack_forget()

        webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M&feature=youtu.be&t=42")





turtle.exitonclick()
x.mainloop()
```

Comment: [debug help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your *minimal* code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: @Prune Nice link. I'll have to bookmark that. I liked the phrase "rubber duck debugging." Thanks.

Comment: As you'll notice, the link isn't mine; it's a gift from some long-time SO contributor, well before I joined.

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables and which part of code is executed - this way you can find what makes problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because turtle keeps position as `float` so `xcor()`, `ycor()` give `float()` values and `print()` shows rounded value ie. `25.0` but real value is `25.000000000000063948846218409016728401184082031250000000`

You have to use `int()` values ie.

```
    x = int(p1.xcor())
    y = int(p1.ycor())
```

and use `x`, `y` to change direction.

Or use cell number to change direction.

Comment: Thanks, that works for player one but not for p2, any ideas?

Comment: Use `print()` to see values in variables and to find problem - ie. `print("%.54f" % p2.ycor())`. `p2.ycor()` is little different then `p1.ycor()` and it has `24.999...` instead of `25.000...` and `int(24.9999)` gives `24`. Use `round()` instead of `int()` (or use cell number to change direction).